# White circle on SQL Server 2008 standard edition db in Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server-2008

What does it mean when my servers have a white circle instead of a green circle with a white arrow in it in SQL Server Management Studio?

It takes a noticeably longer time (5-10 seconds) to connect and if I right click on it the start and stop options are grayed out. How can I change it to green?

Note: I am connecting from a public domain to a local domain and I seem to have no connectivity issues. Port 1433 on both servers are open as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this behavior before when we moved our server behind a more restrictive firewall. At this time I can not remember which actual port exception was needed in the firewall but I do remember it was not the same port as the SQL Engine (default 1433 port).

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. I am on a sharepoint server that is in the DMZ but the SQl server is still in the local domain.

Answer (score 3):

This means Management Studio can't determine whether or not the service is running. This may not necessarily be a connectivity issue, it could also be one of permissions.

Comment: How do I resolve it? Although it is not causing any problems as of now, I dont want it to cause mayhem in the near future.